# Removing Duplicates From 1 Column Assocatied with a Name in Multiple Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, deduplication

I'm trying to create a pivot table to count the number of events a person has attended. In the example below, I'd like to remove the duplicates associated with a specific person.

Joyce is listed correctly, but Sharon is listed as having attended Event 1, two times. In the pivot table, this will give her count of attending two events, when in reality she would be getting credit for attending Event 1, twice.

Same goes for Jim, he is listed attending Conference 1 and Conference 2, twice.

How do I remove the duplicates associated with an individual and not have duplicates removed from the column entirely (only 1 Conference 1 can be listed). I tried highlighting Name and Event, Remove Duplicates, and it seemed to work for some of the data, but something like 3,000 rows were left without a full name of an event listing next to them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Excel Table:

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/562750/how-to-remove-duplicate-records-in-excel-2007 - teylyn answer - Data ribbon > Remove Duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use Remove Duplicates under Data Tab and check my data has headers
under Columns check only 2 columns:

- Full Name
- Event
  then Ok
  it will remove duplicates and keep one Row (for multiple duplicates)